# Task.Run cancellation

Tags: c#, xamarin

before I update VS for mac I use

```
using (var cancelSrc = new CancellationTokenSource())
                    {
                        using (UserDialogs.Instance.Loading("Connecting", cancelSrc.Cancel, "Cancel"))
                        {
                            await device.Connect().ToTask(cancelSrc.Token);
                        }
                    }
```

to connect a ble device

after updated IDE comes up a error "operator '.' cannot be applied to operand of type void"

that I use

```
await Task.Run(() => 
                            {
                                cancelSrc.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                                while (!cancelSrc.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                                {
                                    device.Connect();
                                }
                            },cancelSrc.Token);
```

instead of `await device.Connect().ToTask(cancelSrc.Token);`
but when I tapped on the loading screen in app it does nothing but keep connecting , and seems the connection will not finish forever.
please give me some help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that everyone is not interested in my question,I solve it by myself with some way looks not so smart.
Here's my solution:implement a Task method

```
public async Task ConnectDevice(IDevice device,CancellationTokenSource cancelSrc)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            device.Connect();
            while ((cancelSrc.Token.IsCancellationRequested==false)&&(device.IsConnected() == false))
            {

            }

        }, cancelSrc.Token);
    }
```

and when I want to connect I do like this:

```
await ConnectDevice(device, cancelSrc);
```

this works for me